# “ErrorException Trying to get property 'balance' of non-object"

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem “ErrorException
Trying to get property 'balance' of non-object"

**In line 174**
Hope you can help me

- I want to try to send the registered user in the database reward points because of completing a task
  The points earned are important points -

Code

```
    public function offerwall($id,Request $req)
    {
        $now = Carbon::now();
        
        $offerinfo=DB::table('offerwall')->where('id',$id)->get();
        $postbinfo=DB::table('postback')->where('offerwall_id',$id)->get();
        
        if($offerinfo && $postbinfo){
            $offerwall=$postbinfo[0]->offerwall_name;
            $userid=$req->query(strtok($postbinfo[0]->p_userid, '='));
            $payout=$req->query(strtok($postbinfo[0]->p_payout, '='));
            $ip=$req->query(strtok($postbinfo[0]->p_ip, '='));
            $offerid=$req->query(strtok($postbinfo[0]->p_campaing_id, '='));
            $offername=$req->query(strtok($postbinfo[0]->p_offername, '='));
            
            if($offername==""){$offername="offer completed";}
            
            $fetchcoin= Users::find($userid);   
/*line 174*/ $currentcoin= $fetchcoin->balance;   
            $total= $currentcoin+$payout;
            $trns = DB::table('transaction')
            ->insert(['tran_type'=>'credit',
                        'user_id'=>$userid,
                        'amount'=>$payout,
                        'ip'=>$ip,
                        'eventId'=>$offerid,
                        'type'=>$offername.' Credit',
                        'remained_balance'=>$total,
                        'offerwall_type'=>$offerwall,
                        'admin_remarks'=>$offerwall.' '.$offername.' Completed',
                        'remarks'=>$offername.' Completed' ]);
            $fetchcoin->balance=$total;
            $fetchcoin->save(); 
            
          
           
    }
```

Comment: the statement `$fetchcoin= Users::find($userid)` returns `null` probably because whatever stored in `$userid` cannot be found in the `users` table thus you are trying to access a property called `balance` of non-object (`null`, probably, in your case).

Answer (score 0):

Need to be sure that return type of `Users::find($userid)` is object, before access a property. Use `var_dump` or `gettype` to check. Maybe return type is an array so `$fetchcoin["balance"]`. Also check that return is not Null.